# Display two objects using OpenGL. Textures not behaving as expected

Tags: c++, textures, shader, opengl-3

Hi, I am trying to display two objects using OpenGL viz., 1) a **rotating cube** with a mix of two textures (a **wooden crate** pattern and a **smiley**) in the foreground and 2) **rectangular plate** with just one texture (**dark grey wood**) as a background. When I comment out the part of the code governing the display of *rectangular plate*, the *rotating cube* displays both the textures (*wooden crate* and *smiley*). Otherwise, the cube displays only the *wooden crate* texture and the *dark grey wood* texture is also displayed on the rectangular plate, i.e. the ***smiley texture disappears from the rotating cube***. Please find the images 1) http://oi68.tinypic.com/2la4r3c.jpg (with the *rectangular plate* portion of code commented) and 2) http://i67.tinypic.com/9u9rpf.jpg (without the *rectangular plate* portion of code commented). The relavant portion of the code is pasted below

```
// Rotating Cube ===================================================
// Texture of wooden crate
glActiveTexture(GL_TEXTURE0);
glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, texture1);
glUniform1i(glGetUniformLocation(ourShader_box.Program, "ourTexture1"), 0);

// Texture of a smiley
glActiveTexture(GL_TEXTURE1);
glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, texture2);
glUniform1i(glGetUniformLocation(ourShader_box.Program, "ourTexture2"), 1);

// lets use the box shader for the cube
ourShader_box.Use();

// transformations for the rotating cube ---------------------------------
glm::mat4 model_box, model1, model2;
glm::mat4 view_box;
glm::mat4 perspective;

perspective = glm::perspective(45.0f, (GLfloat)width_screen/(GLfloat)height_screen, 0.1f, 200.0f);

model1 = glm::rotate(model_box, (GLfloat)glfwGetTime()*1.0f, glm::vec3(0.5f, 1.0f, 0.0f));
model2 = glm::rotate(model_box, (GLfloat)glfwGetTime()*1.0f, glm::vec3(0.0f, 1.0f, 0.5f));
model_box = model1 * model2;

view_box= glm::translate(view_box, glm::vec3(1.0f, 0.0f, -3.0f));

GLint modelLoc_box = glGetUniformLocation(ourShader_box.Program, "model");
GLint viewLoc_box = glGetUniformLocation(ourShader_box.Program, "view");
GLint projLoc_box = glGetUniformLocation(ourShader_box.Program, "perspective");

glUniformMatrix4fv(modelLoc_box, 1, GL_FALSE, glm::value_ptr(model_box));
glUniformMatrix4fv(viewLoc_box, 1, GL_FALSE, glm::value_ptr(view_box));
glUniformMatrix4fv(projLoc_box, 1, GL_FALSE, glm::value_ptr(perspective));  
// --------------------------------------------------------------------

// Draw calls
glBindVertexArray(VAO_box);
glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLES, 0, 36);
glBindVertexArray(0);

// Rectangular Plate =====================================================
// Background Shader
ourShader_bg.Use();

// Texture of dark grey wood
glActiveTexture(GL_TEXTURE2);
glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, texture_wood);
glUniform1i(glGetUniformLocation(ourShader_bg.Program, "ourTexture3"), 2);

// Transformations -------------------------------------------
glm::mat4 model_bg;
glm::mat4 view_bg;

GLint modelLoc_bg = glGetUniformLocation(ourShader_bg.Program, "model");
GLint viewLoc_bg= glGetUniformLocation(ourShader_bg.Program, "view");
GLint projLoc_bg = glGetUniformLocation(ourShader_bg.Program, "perspective");

glUniformMatrix4fv(modelLoc_bg, 1, GL_FALSE, glm::value_ptr(model_bg));
glUniformMatrix4fv(viewLoc_bg, 1, GL_FALSE, glm::value_ptr(view_bg));
glUniformMatrix4fv(projLoc_bg, 1, GL_FALSE, glm::value_ptr(perspective));   
// -----------------------------------------------------------

// Draw calls
glBindVertexArray(VAO_bg);
glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLES, 0, 6);
glBindVertexArray(0);
// =================================================================
```

I have a two questions regarding this code.

- Why is the smiley disappearing?
- Is this how multiple objects are supposed to be rendered? I know OpenGL does not care about objects, it only cares about vertices, but in this case these are separate, disjoint objects. So, should I be organizing them as two VBO's bound to a single VAO or as separate VBO's each bound to two VAO's for each object? Or is the case such that, either way is fine - depends on coder's choice and elegance of code?

Answer (score 1):

You are using the same shader, same matrices and you have the same geometry type for the two objects (triangles), so why set the shader twice ?
Did you try to;

- Set shader
- Bind buffer #1
- Bind texture #1
- Draw object #1
- Bind buffer #2
- Bind texture #2
- Draw object #2